# return ticker for maxvalue per day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, max

For each date, I need to return the ticker with the maximum value
for example this is the data table:

```
dt_date     ticker      price  
20121201    A           5   
20121201    B           7  
20121201    C           6  
20121202    A           10  
20121202    B           8  
20121202    C           7
```

so my expected output would be

```
20121201   C            7  
20121202   A            10
```

I've tried some stuff with max but not really getting anywhere, can anyone help?
I'm using SQL server 2012 btw.

Thanks

Comment: Couple questions: 1) What is / is there a primary key on this table? 2) What should be returned if 2 tickers tie for the highest price on a given day? 3) Shouldn't your expected outcome for 20121201 be B 7?

Comment: Hi 1)yes there is called PKID, 2) I guess both of them, 3)yes - whoops typo which has been corrected.

Comment: Show us the ***some stuff*** you've tried. This isn't ***that*** difficult.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: why is `c` with the price of `7` in the `20121201` date? but `A` is with `10` for `20121202`? I get the max price but how are you deciding the ticker?

Comment: @ Aarolama Bluenk I'm sure it isn't that difficult - except if you don't come from an IT/Programing background and are trying to learn.  It might just be that you'd struggle with elementary tasks in my specialist field?

Comment: @SQLseeker - We're not demanding that you be an expert, merely that you [stop being a help vampire](http://whathaveyoutried.com). There's a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a subquery:

```
select t1.dt_date,
  t1.ticker,
  t1.price
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(price) maxPrice, dt_date
  from yourtable
  group by dt_date
) t2
  on t1.dt_date = t2.dt_date
  and t1.price = t2.maxprice
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5f47/1)

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select dt_date, ticker, price
from
(
  select dt_date, ticker, price,
    row_number() over(partition by dt_date order by price desc) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5f47/3)

Note: this returns the max price by date and the `ticker` that is associated with that price.

Comment: Thanks for your help my bad - my data set had some zeros in it, so it returned them all - which is OK, I'll prefilter these out.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @SQLseeker glad you figured it out.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help bluefeet.  I'm new to this, and your resonspe is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok for you!

```
Select dt_date,ticker,price from table t
 where t.price = 
     (select ticker,price from table t2 where t.dt_date=t2.dt_date group by ticker having max(price))
 group by dt_date
```

Davide